# Detecting that files are being copied in a folder

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, lockfile

I am running a script which copies one folder from a specific location if it does not exist( or is not consistent). The problems appears when I run concurently the script 2+ times. As the first script is trying to copy the files, the second comes and tryes the same thing resulting in a mess. How could I avoid this situation? Something like system wide mutex.

I tryed a simple test with `-w`, I manually copied the folder and while the folder was copying I run the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'd:\\folder_to_copy';
if (-w $filename) {
  print "i can write to the file\n";
} else {
  print "yikes, i can't write to the file!\n";
}
```

Of course this won't work, cuz I still have write acces to that folder.
Any ideea of how could I check if the folder is being copied in `Perl` or using`batch commands`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a [lock file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Lock_files). There are myriads of CPAN modules that implement lock files, but most of them don't work on Windows. Here are a few that seem to support Windows according to CPAN Testers:

- <strike>[File::Lockfile](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Lockfile)</strike>
- <strike>[File::TinyLock](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::TinyLock)</strike>
- [File::Flock::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Flock::Tiny)

After having a quick view at the source code, the only module I can recommend is **File::Flock::Tiny**. The others seem racy.

Comment: So in order to know that I am still copying in that folder, I would keep a specific file locked until I finish copying the whole folder and the check would be on that file?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, you have to use a separate file as lock file.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a systemwide mutex, then one "trick" is to (ab)use a directory. The command `mkdir` is usually atomic and either works or doesn't (if the directory already exists).

Change your script as follows:

```
my $mutex_dir = '/tmp/my-mutex-dir';
if ( mkdir $mutex_dir ) {

    # run your copy-code here

    # when finished:
    rmdir $mutex_dir;
} else {
    print "another instance is already running.\n";
}
```

The only thing you need to make sure is that you're allowed to create a directory in `/tmp` (or wherever).

Note that I intentionally do *NOT* firstly test for the existence of `$mutex_dir` because between the `if (not -d $mutex_dir)` and the `mkdir` someone else could create the directory and the `mkdir` would fail anyway. So simply call `mkdir`. If it worked then you can do your stuff. Don't forget to remove the `$mutex_dir` after you're done.

That's also the downside of this approach: If your copy-code crashes and the script prematurely dies then the directory isn't deleted. Presumably the lock file mechanism suggested in [nwellnhof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021570/5830574) behaves better in that case and automatically unlocks the file.

Comment: Are there any cases when this might fail? Any special conditions?

Comment: The whole thing depends on the atomicity of `mkdir`. Under Unix that operation is atomic. Under Windows I'm not perfectly sure and Google stopped being helpful here. I found both statements. _If_ `mkdir` is atomic under Windows, then I don't know of a case where this approach would fail (except for missing permissions).

Answer (score 3):

> As the first script is trying to copy the files, the second comes and
>    tries the same thing resulting in a mess

A simplest approach would be to create a file which will contain 1 if another instance of script is running. Then you can add a conditional based on that.

```
{local $/; open my $fh, "<", 'flag' or die $!; $data = <$fh>};
die "another instance of script is running" if $data == 1;
```

Another approach would be to set an environment variable within the script and check it in `BEGIN` block.

Comment: This is prone to race conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's really smart, but I may move the problem from the folder, as @nwellnhof said, on the file containig the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows-Mutex or Windows-Semaphore Objects of the package
http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/Win32-IPC-1.11/

```
use Win32::Mutex;
use Digest::MD5 qw (md5_hex);
my $mutex = Win32::Mutex->new(0, md5_hex $filename);
if ($mutex) {
     do_your_job();
     $mutex->release
} else {
     #fail...
}
```

Comment: This is also an interesting approach, but I'd like to stick with the modules which came by default.